# Ansible and liquibase integration

Tags: mysql, ansible, liquibase, ssh-tunnel

I have a use-case where I have to run `liquibase` migrations using `ansible` but do not know how to come-around remote connection. One thought is creating ssh tunnel but I am not sure.

Use case:
(on remote server)

- Create N number of databases
- Create database user for each db
- Run liquibase migrations for each db

Remote server is only accessible through ssh and liquibase does not support ssh tunnel ( as far as I know) nor there is ansible module for liquibase.

A hackish way seems to be, before running above tasks:

- Create forward/reverse tunnel for mysql,
- Create N number of databases
- Create database user for each db
- Run liquibase migrations for each db
- Kill the tunnel.

But I am not sure this is best way to solve this issue

Comment: I don't know anything about ansible. But the connection from liquibase (which runs inside a java vm) to the database is JDBC. So if you establish a jdbc connection via an ssh tunnel you should be able to use liquibase with the ssh access you have.

Comment: @Jens , that is the idea left on table , thanks . I was thinking to avoid the tunneling hassle

Comment: I had a similar problem. You could avoid using a tunnel by installing liquibase on the host and running the liquibase commands with Ansible `command` or `shell` module. However for me this turned out to be to complicated and I ended up creating SQL statements with liquibase and deploying those statements with Ansible `mysql_db` module.

Comment: @knowhy check my answer

Comment: What do you mean by "come-around remote connection"?

Comment: I mean e.g migrations on local machine , push them to amazon remote instance ( which does not have java or liquibase) . So liquibase + java + migrations are on local machine

Answer (score 2):

Installing liquibase on serverside with java seems extra overhead therefore, ssh tunnel seems a feasible solution I got around this issue as follow:

Vars:

```
mysql:
    ssh_user: "xyz@{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    forward_port: 3306
    listen_port: 3307
    ssh_key: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }} "
    definer: "'root'@'localhost'"
    backup_dir: "/var/somebackup/location"
```

Tasks :

```
 - name: Kill any active ssh tunnel to current host
    local_action: command bash -c "ps ax | grep ssh |grep -v grep | grep  '{{ mysql.ssh_user }}' |head -n 1| xargs -n 1|head -n 1|xargs kill -KILL"
    sudo: no
    register: ssh_tunnel_end

  - name: Create ssh tunnel to mysql
    local_action:  command bash -c "ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes  -o ConnectTimeout=2 -i {{ mysql.ssh_key }} -f -N -L  {{ mysql.listen_port }}:127.0.0.1:{{ mysql.forward_port }} {{ mysql.ssh_user }}" 
    sudo: no      
    register: ssh_tunnel_start

  - name: Run liquibase migrations for each db
    shell: liquibase --contexts='{{item.1.contexts}}' --username='{{customer.db.root_user}}' --password='{{customer.db.root_password}}' --changeLogFile='update.xml' --url='jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:{{mysql.listen_port}}/{{ customer.prefix }}_{{ item.1.db_suffix }}'   
    args:
        chdir: "{{special_modules.migrations.dest}}/{{item.1.name}}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    sudo: no
    with_subelements:
        - "{{ customer_modules }}"
        - migrations

  - name: Kill reverse ssh tunnel to mysql
    local_action: command bash -c "ps ax | grep ssh |grep -v grep | grep  '{{ mysql.ssh_user }}' |head -n 1|xargs -n 1|head -n 1|xargs kill -KILL"
    sudo: no
    register: ssh_tunnel_end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) 2.0 to install [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) on a remote host is not very difficult:

```
---
- name: Create Liquibase directory
  file: name=/opt/liquibase state=directory mode=0755 owner=root group=root

- name: Install Liquibase
  unarchive:
    src: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/liquibase-parent-{{ liquibase_version }}/liquibase-{{ liquibase_version }}-bin.tar.gz
    dest: /opt/liquibase
    copy: no
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
    creates: /opt/liquibase/liquibase
```

Comment: probably you got my question wrong . I am not installing liquibase anywhere. I am running migrations to remote server using local migrations and liquibase so I have to avoid installing java + liquibase on each server. Please check my answer below

Comment: Why installing JVM and Liquibase is such extra overhead? That's typically how one uses Liquibase.

Comment: I am using Liquibase in php project